# Button Array - which one is pressed? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I tried to dynamically create an array of buttons and i cant quite figure out how i can let a function know which button actually was pressed.. i tried it this way but it does not seem to work out. Any ideas?

```
    public void game_setup(int columns, int rows, int mines)
    {
        //game_destroy();

        //Set Window Size
        this.Height = 50 + Options.y_ini + rows * (Options.size + Options.space);
        this.Width = 20 + 2 * Options.x_ini + columns * (Options.size + Options.space);

        //Setup the playing field
        Button[,] field = new Button[columns,rows];

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            {
                field[i, j] = new Button();

                //Button Size
                field[i, j].Width  = Options.size;
                field[i, j].Height = Options.size;

                //Button Position
                int x = Options.x_ini + i * (Options.size + Options.space);
                int y = Options.y_ini + j * (Options.size + Options.space);
                field[i, j].Location = new Point(x, y);                   

                //Event Handler
                int send_i = i;
                int send_j = j;
                field[i, j].Click += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    field_Click(send_i, send_j);
                };

                //Add the Button to the GameBoard
                Controls.Add(field[i, j]);

            }
        }

        //Distribute the Mines
        //...
    }

    public void field_Click(int x, int y) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("X:" + x + " Y:" + y);
        field[1, 2].Text = "hi";

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your event handler to pass on the sender parameter.  This is a reference to the button that was clicked.

```
field[i, j].Click += (sender, args) =>
{
   field_Click(sender, send_i, send_j);
};

public void field_Click(object sender, int x, int y) 
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    MessageBox.Show(btn.Name + "X:" + x + " Y:" + y);
    field[x, y].Text = "hi";

}
```

Comment: that sounds like a solution to my question, yes. but im afraid i did not quite phrase the question wright..
i need to be able to access all field[x,y]s in this method. is there a way to do that?

Comment: i.e i want to know what button i pressed ( field[1,2] as an example)
and then do stuff to compare it to other field[]s.

Comment: @Timme You need to make the `field` variable a class variable.  As then it will be accessible to all methods in the class.

Answer (score 3):

```
 field[i, j].Tag = new Point(send_i, send_j);
 field[i, j].Click += (sender, args) => {
    Button button = sender as Button;      
    Point p = (Point) button.Tag;
    field_Click(p.X, p.Y);
 };
```

**NOTE**: the point is you can access the actual clicked `Button` via the `sender`, just cast it to `Button` and you can do everything with the clicked `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

```
field[i, j].Name = i +j';
field[i, j].Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                field_Click(sender, send_i, send_j);
            };



public void field_Click(object theButton, int x, int y) 
{
    var currentButton = (Button) sender;

   if ( currentButton.Name == YOUR CODE HERE IF YOU WANT TO CHECK SOMETHING)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("X:" + x + " Y:" + y);
      field[1, 2].Text = "hi";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is just have X and Y when the click happen. You don't need to do much.
First use a very standard click event.

then replace this :

```
int send_i = i;
int send_j = j;
field[i, j].Click += (sender, args) =>
{
    field_Click(send_i, send_j);
};
```

With this

```
field[i, j].Tag = i.ToString() + "|" + j.ToString();
field[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(field_Click);
```

Now change the event handler to be the following

```
private void field_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] sSplitTag = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString().Split('|');
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(sSplitTag[0]);
    int j = Convert.ToInt32(sSplitTag[1]);
}
```

Always try to use the tag to know detail about who your control is. it's what this property is made for... tagging you control so you can recognize him when you see him again.